# How to create a list of actions which corresponds to commands in Java

Tags: java, oop, modularity, code-formatting

I want to control my server by typing commands in the console, but since it is not modular to write something like

```
switch(command)
{
  case 'command1':
    command1();
    break;
  /* And so on */
}
```

in the class Server, how can I create a list of methods bound to functions, that I can easily modify in the future and apply it to other parts of my code ?

Comment: create a interface class, derive a bunch of classes for each command with a common method, put them in a Map object, lookup by key, call method.

Answer (score 4):

```
Map<String, Action> actions = new HashMap<String, Action>();
// TODO populate the map

...

Action action = actions.get(command);
action.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked out for an existing design pattern. Command pattern corresponds to my need.